# Use already uploaded image in Django's ImageField

Tags: django, django-models

Is there an option in ImageField to set the path or an already uploaded image?

My use case is as follows: I want to reutilize the same image in two different content entries. I don't want to upload the image twice or to store two copies of the same image.

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for the FilePathField? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/#filepathfield

Comment: What about a Image model containing a image field and have every model that needs this image refer to the image object with a foreignKey?

Comment: Thanks for your comments, both solve the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just assign the image field from one model instance to another:

```
original_entry = Entry.objects.get(pk=1)

another_entry = Entry.objects.get(pk=2)
another_entry.image = original_entry.image
another_entry.save()

new_entry = Entry.objects.create(image=original_entry.image)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just put an image in it's own model:

```
class Image(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(...)

class ModelA(models.Model)
     image = models.ForeignKey(Image, null=True, blank=True)

class ModelB(models.Model)
     image = models.ForeignKey(Image, null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: Thanks, both answers solve the question but I can only accept one.

Comment: Note that the accepted answer and mine have a slight differences. The accepted answer _assignment dance_ has to preformed on each image update. No problem if images never change. But adding extra logic to ensure consistency if you expect image changes. The separate model works with one image field thus easier to maintain. Downside of a separate model is the db penalty for an extra related image lookup.