# Use already uploaded image in django db

Tags: django, web, django-models, web-deployment

I want to avoid file duplication for  if user already have uploaded an image file in db.

Django ImageField adds an suffix to the image file if the file already exists.

I tried using the solution given by allcaps in following question:

[Use already uploaded image in Django's ImageField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28130604/use-already-uploaded-image-in-djangos-imagefield)

But it only gives me an drop-down option in the upload section, but it doesn't contain anything.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for bothering I forgot to register the model I am using to store images. The answer provided in the link work for me after registering remaining model